# Oracle - How to issue desc command in a procedure within package?

Tags: oracle

It's possible to see only the parameters of a especified procedure into a package?

For example a procedure into dbms_scheduler, something like this:

```
desc dbms_scheduler.create_job
```

It's possible?

Currently I get to see parameters viewing all objects into the package like this:

```
desc dbms_scheduler
```

Comment: dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Comment: I guess that I don't write my realy question, actually I want to get the parameters of a especified procedure into a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DESC / DESCRIBE is a client command (eg SQL*Plus) and not available in PL/SQL.

You can try querying the user_arguments or all_arguments view. It is relatively simple as long as you don't have overloaded procedure / functions and nested data types or weird procedure / variable names.

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I look for, I didn't know this view.